# How to paint black mask in aftereffects?

Tags: photoshop, mask, after-effects, adobe-premiere

Ok, I have some custom effects that I need to paint a mask for in an animation - my idea was either to use AfterEffects or Premiere.

Id prefer AE. Basically what I need is to be able to paint with a soft brush, like in Photoshop, and apply a black mask:

[image: sk]

online and attempting, I can only do hard shape masks. How can I do this?

Comment: stackoverflow is mostly for programming question, this one has more chances to get an answer on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com or https://forums.creativecow.net/

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy Im an idiot. I thought I was posting to graphic design

Comment: @skyguy - assuming you posted on the Graphic Design SE, feel free to delete this question